# SSL - how to trust localhost in Chrome?

Tags: tomcat, google-chrome, ssl

In this previous question, [SSL in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509700/ssl-in-tomcat-7/7521921#7521921), I worked out how to get IE to trust a localhost certificate from my local Tomcat. That's ok for IE, but Chrome still doesn't trust it:

[image: Chrome does not trust localhost certificate]

I understand that Chrome just uses the same certificate store as IE, so why is this happening, or more importantly - how can I trust localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [well-written answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate), that refers to [Configuring SSL Certificate in Linux](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxCertManagement).

The steps from the answer are:

- click the lock icon with an X,
- choose Certificate Information
- go to Details tab
- Click on Export... (save as a file)

Then add your certificate

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n YOUR_FILE -i YOUR_FILE
```